# How I can Add ListView CornerRadius in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, styles

I want to Add style of ListView in XAML for CornerRadius I have one approach but this is not work in my case.
Like this.

```
                    <ListView.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                                    <Border CornerRadius="5">
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <!-- here we go -->
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Pink"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Pink"/>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>

                </ListView.Style>
```

this will doesnot show me my data of ItemsSource so my Listview like this.

```
                <ListView x:Name="MenuBarList" 
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                Height="{Binding MainMenuHeight}"  
                Width="{Binding MainMenuWidth}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                      Foreground="White"
                Background="#FF3D61D0"
                SelectionMode="Single">
```

so how I can add this style.
thank you..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template should include an `ItemsPresenter` so that the `ListView` knows where to display the items. The ItemsPresenter is usually inside a `ScrollViewer` to make it scrollable:

```
                    ...
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                                <Border CornerRadius="5">
                                    <ScrollViewer>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    ...
```

An easier solution is to edit a copy of the [default template](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes):

```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <Border Name="Bd"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                                Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
```